# accesing JSON objects with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, json, object, key

I have a JSON array of objects in this format:

```
 arr = [ {"s1" : [1,2,3]}, 
         {"s2" : [4,5,6]} ];
```

The values I want to access in this array will be determined dynamically. For example, if my dynamic variable is `var num = 2;`, then I want to access the key `s2`. That is, I want the output to be [4,5,6] when my `num` variable is equal to 2.

I tried this:

```
var num_name = "s" + num;
var output = arr[num-1].num_name;
```

But it doesn't work. It only works when I put the actual key name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the to use the key with the name `num_name`, but the key with the name contained in the value of the variable `num_name`. Using the subscript (`[]`) operator will do the trick:

```js
var output = arr[num-1][num_name];
```